# How to search using line number in xml php ?

Tags: php, xml

I have this sample xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rss version="2.0" xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/">
<appConfig authenticate="true"></appConfig>
<device>J0A0AM049303</device><!--100001-->
<device>H0A0AG014628</device><!--100002-->
<device>N0A097016646</device><!--100003-->
</rss>
```

I am searching node value using this code :

```
<?PHP 
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->load('authentication.xml');
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$searchTerm = "11C1AJ013635";
foreach ($xpath->query("//device[contains(text(), '$searchTerm')]/following::comment()") as $comment)
{
    echo "Line number: ".$comment->getLineNo(). '<br/>'.
    " Device number: ".$searchTerm.'<br/>'.
    " Comented number: ". $comment->textContent."<hr>";
    break;
}
?>
```

Now, I just want to search node value when I give line number as search term.
please help me to resolve this. above code is working perfectly, so you can just copy and pase this and edit that according to my new request.
respect to your help.
thanks!

Comment: I assuming that you want to get value of node when you pass line number as search criteria. than you should use flag to track iterations of loop.

Comment: Hi there,
I just confuse with your answer, can you please clarify or just some code to do it
thanks!

Comment: Heloooooo, I am looking some help. plzzzzzzz

Comment: Can anyone help me to resolve this? I put this to get some help, but some how someone has put negative reputation, If I know that correct method I no want to ask from stackOF.

Comment: The line number in XML documents is only informative and not stable, so it's not a good criteria so search for. I assume you've duplicated this here http://stackoverflow.com/q/27716973/367456 as your own question but under a different account (sock puppet) there http://stackoverflow.com/q/27717585/367456 and as I answered http://stackoverflow.com/a/27719002/367456 taking the position of the element if you're looking for a number is perhaps better.

Comment: That being said, never-ever duplicate your own questions only you didn't get an answer so far.

Answer (score 2):

Line numbers in XML documents make not much sense as the whole document could be put into a single line without changing the actual data encoded therein.

So the line-number is more or less informative. Even more bad: It might be ambiguous, there can be more than one *device* element on the same line number.

And one of the biggest downsides which you already address with your question: You can't search for line-numbers in xpath.

So it's perhaps worth to look for a different number that does not have all these negative properties.

What perhaps makes more sense here is the number or position of the `<device>` element found. It can be queried in an XPath expression directly, "`//device[1]`" is the first *device* element in the document.

Additionally your code could benefit by first retrieving the *device* element you're looking for and than checking for the diverse properties you're interested in.

Next to that, you need to properly quote the search term looked for as you do inject the string into the xpath expression directly (my example code makes use of the [`xpath_string()` function](https://hakre.wordpress.com/2013/07/11/mitigating-xpath-injection-attacks-in-php/)).

### Example Code for Element Positions in PHP XPath

I have the XML inside the variable `$buffer` to have the code more portable:

```
$buffer = <<<XML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <rss version="2.0" xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/">
    <appConfig authenticate="true"></appConfig>
    <device>J0A0AM049303</device><!--100001-->
    <device>H0A0AG014628</device><!--100002-->
    <device>N0A097016646</device><!--100003-->
    <device>11C1AJ013635</device><!--100004-->
</rss>
XML;
```

It's then used when the main collaborators **DOMDocument** and **DOMXPath** are set up:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadXML($buffer);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
```

The next part is to query the *device* elements based on the search term. You will find two major differences to your code: First of all, the search term is now quoted to mitigate XPath injection and second the XPath expression is looking for the *device* elements and not yet for the comment after those and third I do not test for text-nodes (`text()`) but search inside the text-content of the device:

```
$searchTerm = "3";

$expression = sprintf("//device[contains(., %s)]", xpath_string($searchTerm));
$devices    = $xpath->query($expression);

printf("Search term: %s; found %d device(s):\n", $searchTerm, $devices->length);
```

The XPath expression `$expression` is:

```
//device[contains(., '3')]
```

With this broad search term "3" and the example XML it creates two results, also shown by the summary output:

```
Search term: 3; found 2 device(s):
```

As all devices searched for are now inside `$devices` it's possible to get all the properties you're looking for (and even more of these) by just iterating over them and obtaining them. I have the following list of properties:

- number of the search result (new)
- comment line number
- comment text
- device position (new)
- device number

```
foreach ($devices as $index => $device) {
    # ... obtain and process the infos from $device ...
}
```

These information can be obtained by either operating on the *device* element `$device` directly or by executing an XPath expression with it as context-node (think as of relative to the element). For example to get the comment node which is yet missing:

```
    $comment = $xpath->query('following::comment()', $device);
```

The xpath expression "`following::comment()`" I've taken from your XPath and it's anchored to `$device` here (see the second parameter to `$xpath->query()`). What follows is the processing of the result of the operation:

```
    if (!$comment || !$comment->length) {
        throw new UnexpectedValueException('Unable to find comment.');
    }
    $comment  = $comment->item(0);
    $line     = $comment->getLineNo();
    $comment  = $comment->textContent;
```

This should be similar to what you already had in your code, `$comment` here temporarily contains the comment node so the line number and the text can be obtained from the comment.

More interesting now is how to obtain the position of the *device* element `$device` that has been found within the document. Again this is done with an XPath expression with `$device` as context-node:

```
$position = $xpath->evaluate("count(preceding::device) + 1", $device);
```

This is pretty simple: The number of *device* elements that are preceding to `$device` plus one is counted. This is the position of the search result.

To complete the list of properties only the device-number or code is left:

```
$number   = $device->textContent;
```

After all the information has been acquired, the information can be output:

```
    echo "--------------------------------\n";
    echo "Device #" . (1 + $index) . ":\n" .
        " Line number: " . $line . "\n" .
        " Device position: " . $position . "\n" .
        " Device number: " . $number . "\n" .
        " Commented number: " . $comment . "\n";
} // foreach
echo "--------------------------------\n";
```

And that's it. This gives the following output:

```
--------------------------------
Device #1:
 Line number: 4
 Device position: 1
 Device number: J0A0AM049303
 Commented number: 100001
--------------------------------
Device #2:
 Line number: 7
 Device position: 4
 Device number: 11C1AJ013635
 Commented number: 100004
--------------------------------
```

With the *Device position* you're now able to address the device later on more distinctively by using it as the position in XPath:

```
//device[1]
```

or

```
//device[4]
```

This is not even more distinct as line-numbers, it also allows you to address the *device* element with an XPath expression alone - something not possible with line-numbers.

---

The example code in full ([online demo](https://eval.in/238553)):

```
<?php
/**
 * http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27717585/resolve-xml-php-node-seach-when-i-give-line-number-as-search-term
 *
 * 27717585
 */

/**
 * xpath string handling xpath 1.0 "quoting"
 *
 * @param string $input
 *
 * @return string
 */
function xpath_string($input)
{

    if (false === strpos($input, "'")) {
        return "'$input'";
    }

    if (false === strpos($input, '"')) {
        return "\"$input\"";
    }

    return "concat('" . strtr($input, array("'" => '\', "\'", \'')) . "')";
}

$buffer = <<<XML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <rss version="2.0" xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/">
    <appConfig authenticate="true"></appConfig>
    <device>J0A0AM049303</device><!--100001-->
    <device>H0A0AG014628</device><!--100002-->
    <device>N0A097016646</device><!--100003-->
    <device>11C1AJ013635</device><!--100004-->
</rss>
XML;

$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadXML($buffer);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

$searchTerm = "3";

$expression = sprintf("//device[contains(., %s)]", xpath_string($searchTerm));
$devices    = $xpath->query($expression);

printf("Search term: %s; found %d device(s):\n", $searchTerm, $devices->length);

foreach ($devices as $index => $device) {
    $comment = $xpath->query('following::comment()', $device);
    if (!$comment || !$comment->length) {
        throw new UnexpectedValueException('Unable to find comment.');
    }
    $comment  = $comment->item(0);
    $line     = $comment->getLineNo();
    $comment  = $comment->textContent;
    $position = $xpath->evaluate("count(preceding::device) + 1", $device);
    $number   = $device->textContent;

    echo "--------------------------------\n";
    echo "Device #" . (1 + $index) . ":\n" .
        " Line number: " . $line . "\n" .
        " Device position: " . $position . "\n" .
        " Device number: " . $number . "\n" .
        " Commented number: " . $comment . "\n";
}
echo "--------------------------------\n";
```